# Show that each number $n$ whose divisors $d$ $=$ $0, 1$ $\pmod 5$ has the form $P(x)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Show that each number $n$ such that each divisor $d$ of $n$ is congruent to $0, 1$ $\pmod 5$ has the representation $P(x) = b^4 - cb^3 - db^3 + c^2b^2 + 2dcb^2 + d^2b^2 - bc^3 - 3bdc^2 + 2bcd^2 - bd^3 + c^4 - dc^3 + d^2c^2 - cd^3 + d^4$

Is this the smallest polynomial representing all numbers with divisors only congruent to $0, 1$ $\pmod 5$?

Thanks for help.

Comment: So, $P(x)$ is constant? There's no $x$ in its definition

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, Monday: this appears to be false. Here are the first few numbers for which I cannot get it to work:

```
1931  =   1931 ::::: 1  3  7  8      Prime !  
1805  =   5 19^2 ::::: 1  4  7  8   
1375  =   5^3 11 ::::: 1  2  8  4   
1361  =   1361 ::::: 1  5  9  8      Prime !  
1181  =   1181 ::::: 1  3  5  7      Prime !  
631  =   631 ::::: 1  1  6  4      Prime !  
275  =   5^2 11 ::::: 1  1  5  3   
125  =   5^3 ::::: 1  2  3  4
```

Apparently what you want is the norm form for $t^4 + t^3 + t^2 + t + 1$ or $e^{2 \pi i / 5}.$ [See page 2 of PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.00531.pdf)

x * x * x * x  + (-w + (-y - z))*x * x * x  + (w * w  + (-3*y + 2*z)*w + (y * y  + 2*z*y + z * z ))*x * x  + (-w * w * w  + (2*y + 2*z)*w * w  + (2*y * y  - z*y - 3*z * z )*w + (-y * y * y  - 3*z*y * y  + 2*z * z *y - z * z * z  ))*x + (w * w * w * w  + (-y - z)*w * w * w  + (y * y  - 3*z*y + z * z )*w * w  + (-y * y * y  + 2*z*y * y  + 2*z * z *y - z * z * z  )*w + (y * y * y * y  - z*y * y * y  + z * z *y * y  - z * z * z  *y + z * z * z * z ))

where you actually do have the freedom  to demand $w=0,$
 giving something of degree four in three variables, similar to the thing you typed.

For the record, i do not really know why it is possible to arrange one coefficient zero. Clearly there are infinitely many representations of $1,$ generally involving coefficients that are Fibonacci numbers in certain patterns, so perhaps there is some sort of argument about minimizing the coefficient of smallest absolute value, forcing a zero coefficient.

x^4 + (-y - z)*x^3 + (y^2 + 2*z*y + z^2)*x^2 + (-y^3 - 3*z*y^2 + 2*z^2*y - z^3)*x + (y^4 - z*y^3 + z^2*y^2 - z^3*y + z^4)

```
1  =    1  ::::: 0  0  0  1
5  =   5 ::::: 0  0  1  -1
11  =   11 ::::: 0  0  1  2
31  =   31 ::::: 0  0  -1  2
41  =   41 ::::: 0  1  2  -1
61  =   61 ::::: 0  0  1  3
71  =   71 ::::: 0  1  4  2
101  =   101 ::::: 0  1  -1  -3
131  =   131 ::::: 0  1  -3  -1
151  =   151 ::::: 0  1  2  4
181  =   181 ::::: 0  0  3  4
```

==================================

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500509
? id = [1,0,0,0; 0,1,0,0; 0,0,1,0; 0,0,0,1]
%1 = 
[1 0 0 0]

[0 1 0 0]

[0 0 1 0]

[0 0 0 1]

? a = [ 0,1,0,0; 0,0,1,0; 0,0,0,1; -1,-1,-1,-1]
%2 = 
[0 1 0 0]

[0 0 1 0]

[0 0 0 1]

[-1 -1 -1 -1]

? h = w * id + x * a + y * a^2 + z * a^3
%3 = 
[w x y z]

[-z w - z x - z y - z]

[-y + z -y w - y x - y]

[-x + y -x + z -x -x + w]

? p = matdet(h)
%4 = x^4 + (-w + (-y - z))*x^3 + (w^2 + (-3*y + 2*z)*w + (y^2 + 2*z*y + z^2))*x^2 + (-w^3 + (2*y + 2*z)*w^2 + (2*y^2 - z*y - 3*z^2)*w + (-y^3 - 3*z*y^2 + 2*z^2*y - z^3))*x + (w^4 + (-y - z)*w^3 + (y^2 - 3*z*y + z^2)*w^2 + (-y^3 + 2*z*y^2 + 2*z^2*y - z^3)*w + (y^4 - z*y^3 + z^2*y^2 - z^3*y + z^4))
?
```

==================================

Comment: What a peculiar response from an otherwise very respected member of the SE.

Comment: @ClydeKertzer. Hi, I don't remember much about this one, but it is clear that I was writing programs to check whether  the question were reasonable; most OP's don't check anything. Had there been any interest I would likely have cleaned up the thing. In any case, the article I linked is pretty good.